# Problems Debugging Mobile Safari via the desktop Web Inspector

Tags: ios, ios7, safari, mobile-safari, web-inspector

I'm trying to debug a problem with mobile Safari.

I'm using the desktop Web Inspector and a connected iPhone, and it basically doesn't work in any useful way.

- DOM elements don't expand. I click on `<div id="content">...</div>` which contains 50 other DIVs and  nothing happens except that the close-div disappears.
- No CSS shows in the right-hand panel for any selected element
- Images can't be loaded (I just get a spinner)

Are there known problems or incompatibilities? I'm using

- Desktop Safari 6.0.5
- iOS 7.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too - you'll need to update to Safari 6.1.